# CSS background-image and background differences

Tags: html, ios, css, background, background-image

I have the following code my background so that the image is slightly opaque.

```
div#home {
    background-size: cover;
    color: #404040;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0.45) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 0.45) 100%), url(/images/sp-bg.jpg);
}
```

However I want it to be fixed. I tried using `background-attachment` but that doesn't work on iOS Safari so i was looking for alternatives and come across:

`background: url(/img.png) no-repeat center center fixed`

I am trying to implement that so it works with my opacity bit like:

```
div#home {
        background-size: cover;
        color: #404040;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0.45) 0%,rgba(0,0,0, 0.45) 100%), url(/images/sp-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
```

However that zooms my image in a lot more than it should be.

The site is accessible at: http://www.shivampaw.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**, it is best to set background-size **after** background-image.

You have also to reset it when background-image is **reset** or **updated** elsewhere (via a class or id )

---

From your question, I was not too sure i understand your issue, but if with the gradient you had an issue and not without it, you may use an inset shadow instead :

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background:url(http://www.shivampaw.com/images/sp-bg.jpg) center center fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  /*box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(0,0,0,0.225);*/
  box-shadow:inset 50vh 100vw rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}
body {/* make html scroll */
  height:200%;
}
```

or set  background-size for both bg :

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 100%) 0 0 scroll no-repeat, url(http://www.shivampaw.com/images/sp-bg.jpg) center center fixed;
  background-size:cover, cover;
}
body {
  /* make html scroll */
  height: 200%;
}
```

Comment: It was your note that fixed it! Make it clearer in the answer and I'll accept it :-)! After I added the background-size after the background it worked and zoomed out of the image again!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `background-size: cover;` at the end(*after the background is set*) and your code should work fine.

By default you have `background-size:initial`. The initial keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default value.
`cover` - Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image.

Comment: I had missed out to mention "at the end". But anyway looks like you got the answer from GCyrillus.